# Is there a way to query the Notification Hub for all the devices that were marked as Inactive by the PNS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Is there a way to query the **Notification Hub** for **all the devices** that were marked as Inactive by the ***PNS***? We need that info in order to remove those users from our back-end server. !!

To get info about the users who have **uninstalled** the app. We need tht info to remove those users from our **local DB**. Pls .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a querying method that will return a list of all inactive devices as the notification hub will un-register devices if the target device TTL is exceeded or PNS response code is "INVALID".

The recommended pattern would to be to check the PNS status code after sending a push notification and removing for your local DB as need be. It can be achieved by using a  [scheduled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) azure function to go through the list of devices still in the local db a removing them based on the PNS status code.